# application is not running on emulator

Tags: android-emulator

When i install my application on android its works fine but when i try to run  on emulator it comes up with the following screen and i am unable to  see my application.

[image]
please guide

Answer (score 0):

Did u close your activity after calling  this browser Activity? if so your entire application will close and browser activity will shown out of your application. I too face this problem in dialog activity. i close my activity after calling dialog activity so my dialog activity shown like your result..

Comment: thanks for your concern , the thing is what when i start the emulator for running my app this browser activity automatically launches without pressing any button , i try to close it down but after few sec it automatically reloads